Необычное поведение метода lineTo() в HTML5 Canvas
Имеется код, вот его фрагмент:


ctx.lineWidth = 50;
ctx.strokeStyle = "olive";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
ctx.lineTo(450, 150);
ctx.lineTo(450, 450);
ctx.lineTo(150, 450);
ctx.lineTo(150, 150);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();



Теоретически код должен рисовать на холсте квадрат, однако на практике получается следующая картинка (обратите внимание на верхний левый угол):

Теперь вопрос: это ошибка в реализации Canvas или с моим кодом что-то не так? [Предположим, что у меня есть функция, рисующая один квадрат и принимающая координаты одного из его углов, длину его стороны и толщину линии и, следовательно, нет возможности каждый раз заново корректировать входные данные последнего метода lineTo()]

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос (начните с заголовка, придав ему осмысленность).

Проблема с вашим кодом. Для быстрого понимания проблемы поставьте ширину линии равную единице.

Поставлено. Быстрого понимания, к сожалению, не случилось. Можно немного поконкретнее, если, разумеется, это не отнимет у вас время?

надо сначала «закрыть» путь, а потом его заполнять. Поменяйте местами closePath и stroke. Ну и последний lineTo тогда будет не нужен, потому что closePath автоматически дорисует отрезок к началу пути.

Alexey Ten, спасибо, это помогло.
